# Outputting text in a form with flow using signals

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside6

Need help with the following task:

There is a main window MainWindow and there is a separate class of a stream in which there is a text. Tell me how to use signals on the plainTextEdit form, which is located on the main form, to display text through signals?

Main window code:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

from Controller.Potok_Controller import Potok_Controller
from View.ui_potok import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_window)

    def open_window(self):
        self.myThread = Potok_Controller()
        # self.myThread.mysignal.connect(self.sendText)
        self.myThread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

UI code of the main window:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'untitledkonQbZ.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.3.1
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit,
    QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(self.frame)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName(u"plainTextEdit")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.frame_2 = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName(u"frame_2")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0442 \u043f\u043e\u0442\u043e\u043a\u0430", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Thread class code:

```
import time

from PySide6.QtCore import QThread

class Potok_Controller(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Potok_Controller, self).__init__(parent)

    def txt(self):
        txt1 = 'test1'
        time.sleep(1)
        txt2 = 'test2'
        time.sleep(1)
        txt3 = 'test3'

    def run(self):
        self.txt()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to implement the `sendtext` method that you have commented out in your `open_window` method, and then create a signal that accepts a string parameter in your `Potok_Controller` class and emit the signal from the threads run method.

For Example:

```
class Potok_Controller(QThread):
    
    mysignal = Signal([str])   # create signal

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Potok_Controller, self).__init__(parent)

    def txt(self):
        txt1 = 'test1'
        time.sleep(1)
        txt2 = 'test2'
        time.sleep(1)
        txt3 = 'test3'
        return txt1 + txt2 + txt3 

    def run(self):
        self.mysignal.emit(self.txt())  # emit the signal with text as parameter
```

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_window)

    def sendText(self, text):  # create the sendText method
        self.ui.plaintextedit.setPlainText(text)

    def open_window(self):
        self.myThread = Potok_Controller()
        self.myThread.mysignal.connect(self.sendText)  # uncomment this
        self.myThread.start()
```